# Version node not found for symbol when static linking libgomp.a compiled with fPIC

Tags: gcc, linker, openmp, ld, fpic

I'm trying to recompile gcc/gfortran with `-fPIC` so that I will be able to statically link the libraries with position-independent compiled objects using

```
# gcc/gfortran configured and compiled with
./configure --disable-multilib --with-pic CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC FFLAGS=-fPIC
```

but run into issues with `libgomp` OpenMP during linking:

```
# linking final binary
gcc -shared -Wl,-t -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' foo.o \
-Wl,-Bstatic -Imumps-5.5.1/include -Lmumps-5.5.1/lib -ldmumps -lmumps_common \
-Imumps-5.5.1/libseq -Lmumps-5.5.1/libseq -lmpiseq -Lmumps-5.5.1/PORD/lib -lpord \
-llapack -lblas -lgomp -lgfortran -lquadmath \
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -lpthread -o foo

...

(/home/user/gcc-7.5.0/lib64/libgomp.a)oacc-host.o
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
-ldl (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so)
(/home/user/gcc-7.5.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/libgcc.a)sfp-exceptions.o
(/home/user/gcc-7.5.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/libgcc_eh.a)unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)atexit.oS
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/home/user/gcc-7.5.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.5.0/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

...

/usr/bin/ld: version node not found for symbol omp_set_nest_lock@@OMP_3.0
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Bad value

...

> nm -s libgomp.a | grep omp_set_nest_lock
gomp_set_nest_lock_30 in lock.o
gomp_set_nest_lock_25 in lock.o
omp_set_nest_lock@@OMP_3.0 in lock.o
omp_set_nest_lock@OMP_1.0 in lock.o
gomp_set_nest_lock__30 in fortran.o
gomp_set_nest_lock__25 in fortran.o
omp_set_nest_lock_@@OMP_3.0 in fortran.o
omp_set_nest_lock_@OMP_1.0 in fortran.o
00000000000001d0 T gomp_set_nest_lock_25
00000000000000a0 T gomp_set_nest_lock_30
00000000000000a0 T omp_set_nest_lock@@OMP_3.0
00000000000001d0 T omp_set_nest_lock@OMP_1.0
                 U gomp_set_nest_lock_25
                 U gomp_set_nest_lock_30
0000000000000110 T gomp_set_nest_lock__25
0000000000000070 T gomp_set_nest_lock__30
0000000000000070 T omp_set_nest_lock_@@OMP_3.0
0000000000000110 T omp_set_nest_lock_@OMP_1.0
```

if I check the symbols in *libgomp* then omp_set_nest_lock@@OMP_3.0 is definitely defined, and libgomp not multiply linked either. I have tried both with gcc 7.5 and 12.2, and dynamic linking (.so) works, but not the static one (.a) so I'm not quite sure what the issue could be here?

Comment: Versioned symbols are the issue, normally static libraries don't have them. You might need to pass `--enable-symvers=no` when building GCC.

Comment: @amonakov thanks, I see, yes now it links without issues but I get warnings `/usr/bin/cmake: /home/user/gcc-12.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available` during compilation and the resulting binary doesn't execute, so something is still wrong

Comment: I just tried and I find that building with `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET="-O2 -fpic"` is sufficient to get PIC/PIE-compatible runtime libraries, no need for `--with-pic`.

Comment: -shared : 
           Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable.  Not all systems support this option.  For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options that were used to generate code (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this option.